# Dependency Inversion Principle: High Level and Low Level module example

Tags: c#, design-principles, dependency-inversion

I was going through the following [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235025/dependency-inversion-principle-understanding-how-both-low-level-components-and) to understand what high-level and low-level modules mean in the context of Dependency Inversion Principle.

As per the explanation given there, is the following code snippet a good/appropriate example?

```
public class HighLevel
{
    private IAbstraction _abstraction;

    public HighLevel(IAbstraction abstraction)
    {
        _abstraction = abstraction;
    }

    public void Act()
    {
        _abstraction.DoSomething();
    }

}

public interface IAbstraction
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class LowLevel: IAbstraction
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a long answer short: yes, this is an example of a Dependency Inversion Principle